# "Corrupted" Access Database

Tags: java, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am replicating a VB.NET program in JAVA. Both versions use Microsoft Access as a database ... While working on the version written in JAVA, I decided to run the program in VB.NET, when from nowhere I get the following message: "Unrecognized database Format".

By inertia (I do not know if this was what caused the whole thing), I opened the database (access 2007) and clicked on "repair and compact". I closed Access and re-run the program in VB.NET ... and nothing, it was the same. I resigned myself so much that I decided to make the database again from 0 ... but surprise, when I try to open the database in Access, Access throw the same error as in VB.NET and it does not even let me see tables or relationships ... then, I remember that the day before, I had uploaded the project in JAVA in my cloud, so I accessed the cloud and re-downloaded the project database and I put it back to VB.NET to see if it ran ... but this time Access throw another different error: "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Object'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.", I try to open the database in Access too, but it tells me the same message as in VB.NET...

The most funny of all, is that if I run the program version in JAVA, it runs completely normal, without complaining about anything ... I can insert, update, delete .... everything normal. I did one last test to see if the database really was not working. I downloaded the database on another computer with Access 2013 ... and the database opened as if nothing has happened.

Some things I have to make clear:

- Originally I did the database in the University, and the version that
  they have is Access 2013.
- In my house I use Access 2007
- I have used this database for a long time without any problems until yesterday.
- If I have used it for a long time, it is clear that I have already downloaded the Access database driver. (32 bits to be specific).
- VB.NET does not recognize the database, but JAVA does.
- I can not open the database in my home using Access 2007

What can I do with this problem?

**EDIT: How I connecting to the Access Database in JAVA**

Here you go

```
public class GestorDB {
private Connection conn;
private final String driver;

public GestorDB(String direccionDB) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+direccionDB);
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return conn;
}
}
```

I think, the reason that I can run the program in JAVA is because when you use UcanAccess driver, you dont need to have instaled Microsoft Access in your computer. . .

Comment: How are you connecting to the Access database from Java? Are you using JDBC? If so, what does your connection string look like?

Comment: I edit my question, there is  the code @GordThompson

Comment: Are you able to provide a download link for a copy of the database file that can be opened in Java but cannot be opened in Access itself?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try creating a new empty database file in Access and then try importing the tables and other objects from your corrupted database.